# Members in a list - LISP

Tags: lisp

I need to write a program in Lisp to see the number of occurrences of a specific character in a list. For example the occurrences of 1 in the following list [1, 2, 3, 1,1]

Comment: You might find inspiration by figuring out 1) how to find the length of a list and 2) how to see if the first item in a list is a specific thing.

Comment: @molbdnilo You could do it iteratively, sure, but it's a natural case for the map/reduce algorithm, which is of course trivial to implement in Lisp. (Everybody thinks Google invented it, of course -- kids these days, no sense of history...)

Comment: @AaronMiller Kids these days have no idea that almost everything in programming is far older than they are. (I suspected this to be an exercise in writing recursive procedures, in preparation for discovering the glories of map and reduce.)

Comment: Lisp? Scheme? Racket? Racket Teaching Language? Iteratively? Recursively? Characters, Numbers, Symbols? Any constraints?

Comment: @uselpa Well, "Lisp" not otherwise qualified generally means ANSI Common Lisp, and the example list given is one of integers. (Well, the syntax is that of a vector, but given that the word "list" is used, and that the asker doesn't seem to know the difference, I'll assume the haystack is represented as a list until further notice.) Other than that, who knows? Our interlocutor here doesn't seem all that inclined to give much thought to his homework, or he'd probably have tried solving the problem on his own before he posted the question here.

Comment: @AaronMiller We can speculate of course, but I would like the OP to answer these questions.

Comment: @AaronMiller ha I didn't read these comments until after I posted my answer, and I see that sure enough my recursive attempt would probably be made more elegant by a map/reduce. I'd love to see someone show that. I guess I'm still at Level 1 in this language :)

Comment: @OpenLearner actually, reduce is a synonym for fold. :) My code is far more inefficient than yours. I just wanted to showcase a few concepts. Any true, practical implementation would be a simple loop, not unlike your code (when and if made tail recursive), only explicitly so.

Comment: @OpenLearner Well, I posted my answer, but I warn you, it'll probably make you yawn.

Answer (score 2):

A list in Lisp is a sequence of *cons* nodes: pairs of pointers - the first to the payload datum, and the second to the rest of the list. E.g. for `[1,2,3,1,1]`,

```
      .
     / \
    1   .
       / \
      2   .
         / \
        3   ...... .
                  / \
                 1   NIL
```

`NIL` is a special value signaling the empty list, such that the system knows not to try to explore it any further. In Scheme,

```
(define NIL '())
```

Recursive list processing paradigm is captured by the notion of [***fold***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), where each node **`.`** is "replaced" with a binary function **`f`**, and the special node `NIL` is replaced with some special "zero" value **`z`**, to create an application chain `(f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (... (f 1 z) ...))))`. In Scheme,

```
(define (myfold f z list)
  (cond
      ((null? list) z)                ; replace NIL with the initial ("zero") value
      (else 
        (f                            ; combine
           (car list)                 ; the payload datum, and the delayed,
           (lambda ()                 ;   by creating a function to calculate it,
             (myfold f z              ;     result of recursively folding 
                     (cdr list))))))) ;       the rest of list
```

That way, the combining function `f` must process two values: one is a node's payload datum, the other is *the (delayed) result* of recursively folding, with the same `f` and `z`, the *rest* of the list after that node.

```
(define (keep-equals v list)
  (myfold
         (lambda (a r)         ; combine ...
           (if (equal? v a) 
             (cons a ... )     ; the same thing goes over the dots, here
             ... ))            ;                                and here
         '()                   ; replace the NIL of the argument list with this
         list))
```

Since the recursive folding results' calculation is delayed by creating a function *to-be-called when the results are needed*, we need to *"force"* that calculation to be performed, when we indeed *need* those results, by *calling* that function.

And if you want to *count* the number of occurrences instead of collecting them in a list, you just need to use a different combining function with a different initial ("zero") value.

In particular, we *build a list* by *`cons`ing* a value onto the rest of list (with NIL as the initial value, the empty list); whereas we *count* by *incrementing* a counter (with 0 as the initial value of that counter).

Calculating e.g. a list's length by folding, we essentially turn its elements each into 1: `length [a,b,c,d,e] == 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + 0))))`. Here, the combining function will need to increment the counter conditionally, only when the payload data are such that we *want* to count them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to lisp myself but here is how I would do it. I haven't looked at the other answer yet from Will so I'll check that out after I post this. The `member` function has the utility of both telling you if it found something in a list, and also returning the rest of that list starting from where it found it:

```
CL-USER> (member '1 '(0 1 2 3))
(1 2 3)
```

You could then recursively call a function that uses `member` and increment a counter from returned values in a variable from a `let`:

```
(defun find1 (alist)
  (let ((count 0))
    (labels ((findit (list)
              (let ((part (member '1 list)))
                (if part
                  (progn (incf count)
                         (findit (rest part)))
                   0))
             count))
      (findit alist))))
```

Here is the result:

```
CL-USER> (find1 '(1 2 3 4 5))    
1
CL-USER> (find1 '(1 1 2 3 4 5))
2
CL-USER> (find1 '(1 1 1 2 3 1 4 5 1 1))
6
```

You could get rid of that unattractive `progn` by using `cond` instead of `if`

**UPDATE**: Here is an updated and more elegant version of the above, based on the comments, that I think would qualify as tail recursive as well:

```
(defun find1 (alist &optional (accum 0))
  (let ((part (member '1 alist)))
    (if part
     (find1 (rest part) (+ accum 1))
     accum)))
```

Here it is in action:

```
CL-USER> (find1 '(1 2 3 4))    
1
CL-USER> (find1 '(1 1 1 1))
4
CL-USER> (find1 '(1 1 0 1 1))
4
CL-USER> (find1 '(0 2 1 0 1 1 0 1 1))
5
```

Comment: if you're using `member`, then there's also [*`count`*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_countc.htm)..., suggested earlier by [user:Vatine]. :) So maybe, to make your exposition fully informative, you'd add your implementation for `member` here, or an outline of it... In any case, it should be possible to make your `findit` tail recursive. :) -- (... but I thought `progn` is fine, `prog1` is fabulous, and `prog` fan-tastic!..) :) -- ((I wonder, do you see your code aligned well, in your browser? I see this through Chrome, and the code is misaligned, because of tabs.))

Comment: @WillNess the alignment showing here for me is identical to how it aligns in my emacs, appears correct. Regarding `progn` Norvig instructs that it should generally be avoided, but mentions that one exception is when dealing with multiple forms in an `if` as I've done here, so I guess it's okay.

Comment: @WillNess correction, the alignment is very slightly off on a couple of lines, i will try to fix.

Comment: now it looks great, but it's still not tail-recursive! Do make it tail-recursive, the function `findit` I mean. You just need to erase one line, and change some indentation and parentheses. :)

Comment: @WillNess let me know what you think of my tail recursive version above; certainly it is a much more elegant algorithm. thanks for the prodding, i just needed to wait until I had a spare moment!

Comment: great! yes, it is TR. :) what I meant though was just to tweak your original code a little bit, as `(labels ((findit (list)
              (let ((part (member '1 list)))
                (if part
                  (progn (incf count)
                         (findit (rest part)))
                  count)))) (findit alist))`. Mutation is *before* the recursive call here, which *is* in tail position - because `if` is in tail position now.

Comment: @WillNess I thought that's what you meant, but I figured that just making the top-level function the recursive call would eliminate need for `labels` function and make the whole thing simpler.

Comment: yes, you've walked an extra distance there. :) btw nothing wrong with `labels`, it makes it a bit more *encapsulated*, isolated, less interaction to be worried about. The trick with using `&optional` for use by recursive calls, I don't like. It makes the mechanics too exposed, prone to misuse maybe? One more thing to worry about. OTOH, it's good here, because you *might* want to specify the initial accum value non-zero. :)

Comment: @WillNess that's a great point, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like pretty well the answers already posted to this question. But it seems like they both involve a fair bit more than the necessary amount of work. On the other hand, given all the thought everyone's put into this, I'm almost embarrassed of how simple my answer is. Anyway, here's what I did:

```
(defun count-things-in (needle haystack)
  "Count the number of NEEDLEs in HAYSTACK."
  (reduce '+
          (map 'list
               #'(lambda (straw)
                   (if (equalp straw needle) 1 0))
               haystack)))

(count-things-in 1 '(1 2 3 1 1))
;; => 3
```

It's pretty straightforward: you just map over HAYSTACK a function which returns 1 for an element which is EQUALP to NEEDLE or 0 for an element which isn't, and then reduce the resulting list by `+`. For the given example list, the map operation results in a list `(1 0 0 1 1)`, which the reduce operation then treats as `(1 + (0 + (0 + (1 + 1))))`, which evaluates to 3.

Benefits of this approach include the use of an equality predicate loose enough to work with strings as well as numbers, and with numbers of different types but the same value -- that is, `(equalp 1 1.0)` => `t`; if you desire different behavior, use another equality predicate instead. Using the standard MAP and REDUCE functions, rather than implementing your own, also gives you the benefit of whatever optimizations your Lisp system may be able to apply.

Drawbacks include being not nearly as impressive as anyone else's implementation, and being probably not low-level enough to satisfy the requirements of the asker's homework problem -- not that that latter especially dismays me, given that this answer *does* satisfy the stated requirement.

Comment: whether code is "impressive" seems moot to me, if it works and does so without a lot of extraneous filler, then it's good. so I like this approach too. What I really really love about Lisp, however, is that so many different solutions can be derived for seemingly banal problems, and that each one reveals creativity available in both the language and the programmer.

Comment: @OpenLearner Glad you like it! The "impressiveness" disclaimer wasn't really honest; it was intended to fend off potential cavils originating in the habit I've observed, among a subset of Lispers, to prefer hand-rolled solutions over those which make use of the (by comparison with most other languages exceptionally broad) standard library.

Comment: that makes no sense to me. the power of Lisp and of some other languages comes from a rich set of built-in tools that the programmer can lean on to do heavy lifting. makes development faster and safer to use standard tools others have built and tested over many years.

Comment: In this ongoing challenge, I have updated my answer to provide an even simpler recursive algorithm.